# Is there a way to force immutable.js to use string id's?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm using immutable.js, some times I'm passing string keys and some times I'm passing numeric keys to my immutables.

As a result, a `Immutable.Map` can have two identical children like so:

```
Map({
    1: foo,
    '1': bar,
});
```

which is something **I REALLY - *don't* - want**!

Unfortunately immutable is not strict enough with key types, and that causes me a lot of headache.

Is there a way to force immutable.js to convert all numeric keys to strings before it saves'em ?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can create a proxy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) on your object and check for an already existing key (manually cheking every possible type of key) on an access or `push`

Comment: `some times I'm passing string id's and some times I'm passing numeric id's to my immutables` why? a string ain't a number. `Unfortunately immutable is not strict enough with id types` In contrary. It maps precisely the keys you give it. Check out the native `Map` class. It behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Proxy ([MDN Documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)) that will check for an already existing key (whatever the type) in the object on a `set` accessor, like this:

```
var handler = {
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
        if (obj[String(prop)] == undefined && obj[Number(prop)] == undefined) {
            obj[String(prop)] = value
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Already exists")
        }
    }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, handler);

p[1] = "test"  // p: { 1: "test" }
p["2"] = "foo" // p: { 1: "test", 2: "foo" }
p["1"] = "bar" // Throws an "Already exists" error
```